# Determine whether a matrix is othrogonal

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I need to determine if the following matrix is orthogonal

$A =  \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 \\
0 & 0 \\
1 & -1 
\end{pmatrix}$

Here is what I did:

$u \cdot v = (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \cdot -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}) = 0$

$||u|| = {\sqrt{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + 0 + (\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}})^2 = 1$

$||v|| = {\sqrt{(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})^2 + 0 + (-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}})^2 = 1$

This should indicate that the matrix is orthogonal, however, the answer in the book says it is not orthogonal and I can't see where I went wrong

Comment: Shouldn't orthogonal matices be $n\times n$?

Comment: I suppose that is where my mistake is. I guess I got a bit too caught up and overlooked something as simple as that

Comment: Orthogonal matrices are square matrices that have the property: $A^T = A^{-1}$.

Answer (score 1):

Your matrix satisfies $A^TA=I_2$, that is the columns are orthonormal. Such matrices are useful when you want to define the polar decomposition of a $m\times n$ matrix $M$ with $m\geq n$ and $rank(M)=n$. The decomposition is $M=US$ where $U$ is a $m\times n$ matrix with orthonormal columns and $S$ is a $n\times n$ SDP matrix. More precisely $S=\sqrt{M^TM}$ and $U=MS^{-1}$.